# Android Studio error failed to resolve

Tags: android-studio

pls help me. i install Android studio and create project but error. I try reinstall but without effect. Sorry my english very bad :(

```
package com.example.dellap.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

[image Erro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HekwB.png)

Answer (score 0):

Remove junit dependency from the project.